# Applescript to find the newest folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find the folder which has been last modified. (Actually, I'm only interested in that folder and not an ordered list.) I'm getting an -10010 error.

```
tell application "Finder"
try
    set latestFolder to item 1 of (sort (get name of folders of folder ("/Users/c64/Desktop" as POSIX file)) by creation date) as alias
    set folderName to latestFolder's name
end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the `name` of the last modified `folder` on the **Desktop**, then this will do it:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set latestModifiedFolderName to name of item 1 of (sort every folder by modification date)
end tell
```

---

By the way, the **AppleScript Dictionary** for **Finder** does not contain terms `POSIX file` or `POSIX path` and when using e.g. `POSIX file` inside of a `tell application "Finder"` *block*, **Finder** will throw a *non-fatal error* if it can be *coerced* into an `alias`, otherwise it can throw a *fatal error*. That said, if you are dealing with a `POSIX path`, it's probably best to pass it to **Finder** as an `alias`, and I'd recommend *coercing* the `POSIX path` to an `alias` before passing it to **Finder**, e.g.:

```
set thisFolderPath to POSIX file "/Path/To/Some/Folder" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set latestModifiedFolderName to name of item 1 of (sort every folder of thisFolderPath by modification date)
end tell
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above is just that, and does not include any *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* for any *example code* presented and or *code* written by the oneself.

Comment: You can even omit `of (path to desktop)` because the desktop folder of the current user is the *root* folder of the Finder

Comment: Even `of desktop` is actually not needed 

Comment: @user3439894 I found I had to add `of last item` to get the newest folder, rather than the oldest. Thanks!